sf scanner run dfa is scanning files not included in --target
When running the following command: sf scanner run dfa --target "force-app/main/default/classes/ActionItemTriggerHandler.cls,force-app/main/default/classes/ActionItemTriggerHandlerUtility.cls" -f sarif -o dfa-results.sarif the scanner is running on files that are not included in the value provided to --target.
As an example the above gives me:
Error (1): Remove unreachable code to proceed with the analysis: /Users/matt/prod/xxxxx/force-app/main/default/classes/AccountStructure.cls,AccountStructure:387

That AccountStructure.cls file is not part of the classes passed into --target. I would expect that only the 2 classes provided would be scanned.
Any help would be appreciated.
